# Regexp_like will not accept string as a column

Tags: plsql, regexp-like

Regexp_like needs the following attributes (column, 'regex pattern','optional')

I have a table with all the parameters that this function should collect. The problem is that Regexp_like reads the string "o.REGEX_SEARCH_COLUMN" as a string not a column and that this is a "complex" loop for a beginner like me so I don't know how/if I should use EXECUTE IMMIDIATE or if there is another solution.

```
for o in (select platform, regex_search_column,regex_pattern,regex_optional 
from TABLE1)
    loop
        UPDATE TABLE2 SET Responsible = o.platform where regexp_like 
    (o.regex_search_column,o.regex_pattern,o.regex_optional);
    end loop;
```

Comment: Hi Hippo welcome to SO. Please review the help sections [ask] and since you're asking for code help also see [mre].

Comment: Please **edit your question** and provide information about the values of REGEX_SEARCH_COLUMN, REGEX_PATTERN, and REGEX_OPTIONAL. Otherwise we're guessing. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I hope this is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by creating a string for the entire SQL query and then  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE the string inside the loop.